# Group and count record value in same transformation

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl, dataflow

I'm currently trying to figure out how ETL works in MVS (note XP-edtion).
I've configured my input data and it's something like this:

```
ProductID             Quantity           ActualCost

885                   1                  15
893                   3                  5 
885                   6                  15
```

these are just 3 dummy rows but what I want it to do is the following:

```
ProductID             Quantity           TotalCost
885                   7                  105
893                   3                  15
```

So it has to count up the quantities and multiple them with the actual cost. I've figured out the output, but not the transformation.

Does anybody has a suggestion on what Data flow transformation tool I should use? Or is this only possible using SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't manage to understand you clearly, but YES, it can be done with SQL Query. Simple one:

```
SELECT 
ProductID, 
sum(Quantity) as Quantity, 
sum(Quantity*ActualCost) as TotalCost
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ProductID
```

Comment: thanks for the query, I'm currently starting to find out how it's done with SSIS. I'll post my answer should i find it before someone else replies